# Autocomplete doesn't work on Symfonys SplFileInfo(Finder) method in foreach

Tags: phpstorm

I'm doing the Symfony Tutorial and everything works fine, but PhpStorm won't autocomplete the `getRealpath()` or the other `$file` methods in this tutorial (only the one in the `foreach` loop the others do really good).
[Symfony Tutorial Finder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html)

First I thought it's a problem with Symfony because I trusted PhpStorm :)
Do I have to change something? I excluded the var/cache folder

Comment: Just tried it, works perfect! thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like PhpStorm cannot figure out the correct type when iterating over `$finder` collection (which is rather expected considering how it works).

You can easily solve this by adding typehint via PHPDoc comment (e.g. place it just before or inside `foreach` loop):

```
/** @var SplFileInfo $file */
```

Make sure that it will be `\Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo` and not just `\SplFileInfo` (standard PHP class).

**P.S.**
You may also try installing and enabling Symfony plugin -- *maybe* (have not used it myself) it will provide such typehints automatically/internally so no such manual steps would be required.

Comment: allready installed, it works really great, this is why i was wondering :)

Answer (score 1):

also direct support for PhpStorm 2016.1+ now in Symfony core see: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/19036